# Extract AR coefficient from nmle::gls

Tags: r, nlme

I am running a `gls` model with 1 AR term and would like to see what the `coefficient` is and whether it is significant within the model; however, it is not printed as part of the `summary()` output. Is there any way to extract it?

```
data(iris)
gls = nlme::gls(Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length, data=iris, 
      correlation = corARMA(p=1), method= "ML")
summary(gls)
```

Comment: Try: ```nlme::coef(gls)```

Comment: `gls$coefficients`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions; both code options print the coefficients for the intercept and Petal.Lentgth but I would like to know if adding the AR is significant and what coefficient it has.
`Coefficients:
 (Intercept) Petal.Length 
  -0.3335689    0.4079147`

Comment: related question: what means to add an arma term in a not-time-series data?

Answer (score 3):

Are you asking to see Phi and whether the model is significant relative to independent residuals?

```
library(nlme)
fm <- gls(Petal.Width ~ Petal.Length, data = iris, 
      correlation = corARMA(p=1), method= "ML")

coef(fm$modelStruct$corStruct, unconstrained = FALSE)
##       Phi 
## 0.2824751 

fm2 <-  update(fm, correlation = NULL)
anova(fm, fm2)
##     Model df       AIC       BIC   logLik   Test L.Ratio p-value
## fm      1  4 -53.46889 -41.42635 30.73444                       
## fm2     2  3 -43.59109 -34.55919 24.79555 1 vs 2 11.8778   6e-04
```

As mentioned in the comments `intervals` can also be used here. In this example it gives a one-row matrix whose `est.` column is Phi.

```
intervals(fm)$corStruct
##         lower      est.     upper
## Phi 0.1160876 0.2824751 0.4334412
## attr(,"label")
## [1] "Correlation structure:"

intervals(fm)$corStruct["Phi", "est."]
## [1] 0.2824751
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I had not appreciated that Phi represents the AR term.  I also found I can extract Phi with 95%CIs using `intervals(fm2)`